# Can't compare characters

Tags: c

I have 2 problems:

first problem is that I cant in `for (apr = 0; apr < aprno; apr++)` add chars one by one. For example, if I have aprno = 4, after entered A it asks for 4th apr., but It works when I enter AAAA..., also it works with integers only

second problem is char and int comparsion. I know that I cant compare them, but I didnt have found solution how to do it anywhere.

```
addnoaprons:
    system("cls");
    printf("Add number of available aprons: ");
    scanf("%d", &aprno);
    goto addtypeaprons;

addtypeaprons:
    if (aprno < 1) goto addnoaprons;
    else {
        system("cls");  
        printf("Add types for %d aprons total:", aprno);
        for (apr = 0; apr < aprno; apr++)
            {   
                system ("cls");
                printf("Aprons total: %d", aprno);
                printf("\n\nNo. %d apron type: ", apr + 1);
                scanf("%c", &pismapr[apr]);
                if (pismapr == 'A') poleapr[apr] = 1;
                if (pismapr == 'B') poleapr[apr] = 2;
                if (pismapr == 'C') poleapr[apr] = 3;
                if (pismapr == 'D') poleapr[apr] = 4;
                else goto addtypeaprons;
            }
            goto showaprons;
        }
```

Comment: I am curious why the `goto`s?

Comment: oh, fun... someone trying to code assembly in C... to implement features that could be done with a shell script. Lord, why?

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear.  Can you provide a full, compilable example and explain what input you give it, what output you expect and what output you get please?

Comment: Ooh, [`goto`](http://xkcd.com/292/)s *shivers*. Also `system("cls")` is going to be fun in non-Windows shells.

Comment: What's the question here? In C you can compare a char and an int (cast the char to an int and use ==) but somehow I don't think that's what you want to do. One of my first suggestions for you stop using goto's your code is spaghetti like already I would hate to see this when you get too 1000's of lines. Think of the poor dev who has to pick this up after you.

Comment: @TheKingDave You don't even have to cast `char` to `int` or vice-versa, you can use them interchangeably in C, unless there's some edge case of which I'm unaware.

Comment: @Kninnug - may be he isn't going to be running it on non-Windows shells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pismapr` looks to be an array of `char`; you can't compare it directly to a single `char`. You need to compare just the array element of interest:

```
if (pismapr[apr] == 'A') poleapr[apr] = 1;
```

P.S. I have to tell you, this is some of the weirdest looking C code I've seen in ages. Instead of jumping around with `goto`, you should move blocks of code into functions, and then call them in a loop; i.e.,

```
while (aprno < 1)
    aprno = readaprno();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1: Huh?

I have no clue what your first problem is and couldn't really understand what you were asking for that one. Sorry.

## Problem 2: Comparing ints to chars

Yes, you can compare `int`s and `char`s, within reason. What you probably don't want to do it to compare the address of a pointer to a `char` though.

When I see your question and this:

```
scanf("%c", &pismapr[apr]);
```

I can only assume that you mean that `pismapr` is an array of `char`s or `int`s, as I don't see the declaration. So you probably want to switch these:

```
if (pismapr == 'A')
```

to:

```
if (pismapr[apr] == 'A')
```

But that's assuming the type of pismapr, which we don't know with your snippet.

## Problem 3: Gotos

Lose them. Really. Or tell me why you need them.

## Problem 4: Invoking `system()`

Just don't. It's a bad idea, and you probably can do that some other way. If you really want to do this, are you sure you need to do all that with a C program, and not a shell script instead?

Comment: Gee, I rubbed some people the wrong way. Sorry if I offended you :)